# How to create JAXWS web service server skeletons from wsdl ( not in IDE)

Tags: wsdl, jax-ws, pojo, stubs

i can't find any where how to create web service from server skeletons ( java pojo's )from 
wsdl using JAXWS. The only tutorials I see are using automated wizard in NetBeans and and axis2 in eclipse. Can someone please give me hints on how to generate server side classes from given wsdl?

Thanks

UPADATE:
I just need to do :
wsimport.bat -Xendorsed SOAP.WSDL
and it creates the artifacts. 
But now how do I implement it in the server ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to client side classes, wsimport also generates a SEI (Service Endpoint Interface). All you need to do is creating an implementation for that.

Then it should be ready for deployment in your application server.

Answer extended:

If you are using Metro, [this](http://metro.java.net/guide/Deploying_Metro_endpoint.html) is a tutorial on how to map your SEI and SIB (Service Implementation Bean) to the config files and get it ready for deployment.

Comment: im using Tomcat server . how different it is ?

Comment: it should be exactly the same as the tutorial above. Nevertheless, this is an example of how to do it in Tomcat: http://puretech.paawak.com/2010/03/09/running-jax-ws-with-tomcat/. Also bear in mind the potential class loading issues due to jaxb version mismatching:http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2009/04/tip_for_using_j.html

Comment: The Metro tutorial link is broken. Does anyone know of an alternate?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using wsdl2j during build phases using maven or ant.  Also quite good is the cxf codegen plugin for maven.

Comment: i use ant , dont use maven. also wsdl2j is axis2 tool ?

Comment: Yes, look here to see how to use with ant http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/CodegenToolReference.html .

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by [kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662343/1845976), this can be done with [cxf](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html). They also maintain a [maven plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).
Here's an example on how to generate a server side implementation skeleton:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>src/main/gen</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/yourWsdl.wsdl
                        </wsdl>
                        <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/yourWsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        <!--  Generate WS impl Skeleton -->
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `-impl` option will create a skeleton `impl` class that provides a basic implementation for your `@WebService` interface on the server side (provider). Note that this also create a `Service` class (consumer/client side).