# Generate JAXWS (Metro) WebService from WSDL

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, wsimport

I have used wsimport to generate client code for web services and now would like to generate server code.  I've come across a couple of posts that state that wsimport generates both client and server code at the same time.  This has me a bit confused.  This question has a link to a tutorial, but unfortunately the link is out of date (content moved/deleted):

[How to create JAXWS web service server skeletons from wsdl ( not in IDE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662236/how-to-create-jaxws-web-service-server-skeletons-from-wsdl-not-in-ide/7663285#comment12544738_7663285)

Can anyone point me to another resource on how to use wsimport to generate the server side classes and/or use the classes I already have as a web service (and not the client)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no skeleton needed in JAX-WS. You simply implement the (generated) port type interface, and fill in the implementation of the methods of your web service.
You then annotate your implementation class with `@WebService` and it's ready to be deployed in a JavaEE container. For a non-EE container you will need to do some extra configuration, but since you didn't specify the container, I'll stop here.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting your answer.  I got side-tracked with other issues.